# How to access parent service function from a component using Angularjs 1.5?

Tags: angularjs

I have a main app module which doesn't have its own controller. It only have one service which consists of few methods. There are 2 independent components which are modules themselves. They are injected in the main module. Basically, I want to get an event inside component1 which will call the service method inside the main app module, which in returns call a method in component2.

I have passed Service Name in component1 controller but when I call it, it throws error of undefined function.

I tried to inject Service Dependency in Component1 module, but it throws error of unable to initialize component1 module.

I am also new to components concept, I think I am making some basic mistake in implementation. Furthermore, if there is another better way to call methods of one independent component from other component, then, please let me know.

**main module:**

```
(function () {
   "use strict";

   var app = angular.module('allocationMapsApp', ['availableTrucks','assignedJobs','ui.bootstrap']);

   //cart service
   app.factory("assignedJobsService", function() {

      var showAssignedJobs = function(truck) {
         console.log("I am in service");
      };

      return 1;
   });

})();
```

**component1 module:**

```
(function () {
   "use strict";

   var availableTrucks = angular.module('availableTrucks', ['ui.bootstrap']);

})();
```

**component1 code:**

```
(function () {
   "use strict";

   angular.
   module('availableTrucks').
   component('availableTrucks', {
      templateUrl: 'template.html',
      controller: function AvailableTrucksController($http,assignedJobsService) {
         var self = this;

         self.selectTruck = function(data) {

            assignedJobsService.showAssignedJobs(98);
         };
      }
   });
})();
```

**Component2 Module:**

```
(function () {
   "use strict";

   var assignedJobs = angular.module('assignedJobs', ['ui.bootstrap']);

})();
```

**Component2 Code:**

```
(function () {
   "use strict";

   angular.
   module('assignedJobs').
   component('assignedJobs', {
      templateUrl: 'template.html',
      controller: function AssignedJobsController($http) {
         var self = this;

         self.fetchAssignedJobs = function () {
            var url = 'index.php';

            $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
               console.log("Success");
               console.log(response);
            }, function(response) {
               console.log("Failed");
               console.log(response);
            });
         };
      }
   });
})();
```

Comment: did you check the order of js in index.html

Comment: @Ritchie The main app module js comes first after that component1 and component2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why throws error of **undefined function**.?

You are not returning `assignedJobsService` instance.You returning literal `1` which is dont have `showAssignedJobs` function.

return instance of `assignedJobsService`.

```
app.factory("assignedJobsService", function() {
      var services = {}
      services.showAssignedJobs = function(truck) {
         console.log("I am in service");
      };

      return services ;
   })
```

;

Comment: That's great. It starts working and console the service message. Can you guide me, now how can I call a function of component2?

Comment: which function from where?

Comment: I will have a function fetchAssignedJobs() inside the controller of component2. I want to call it from the service.

Comment: For Example, 
`services.showAssignedJobs = function(truck) {
         console.log("I am in service");
         fetchAssignedJobs(); // this call the method of component2
      };`

Comment: @NuttyProgrammer `fetchAssignedJobs` is defined in the controller.Its not possible to call it from service/factory.You can put that function in another service/factor and call it from `component1` and `assignedJobsService`

Comment: I can try to emit an event on $rootScope and get it from controller, what do u think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141431/discussion-between-nutty-programmer-and-ritchie).

Answer (score 0):

Try to give different name to component ,not same as module name.

Comment: After changing component name, nothing improved.
now, module: availableTrucks   component: availableTrucksComponent

Answer (score 0):

First thing first. Avoid build your code in your module like:

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('controllerName', function() {})
```

Best practice is create separate file / function to handle your controllers, services etc like:

```js
function controllerName() {

}

angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('controllerName', controllerName);
```

Second thing. You are injecting `assignedJobsService` into your controller. Where are you exactly define this service name like that one? That can be a reason why your service is undefined.

Third this try keep name of your module and controllers etc not the same that can be tricky to deal with it later. I would recommend add prefix at the end of your component name as componentNameComponent or moduleNameModule etc.

Last thing take a look at this style guide for angularjs with es5:

https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-styleguide/tree/angular-old-es5

or if you are fell free to go with es6 what I would recommended for you take a look at this:

https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-styleguide

Comment: I have service defined in main app module, which I have injected in the component1 controller. I am messing this dependency injection stuff.

Comment: Ok. Try return that `showAssignedJobs` method name in this service.